# PHP get_file_contents() function timeout

Tags: php

I have a function which is getting my sql dump data into the variable. which is about 20MB. I need to read the data and transfer it over api.

```
public function fileGenerate()
    {
            $dumpData = $myController->generate();
            $opts = array(
                'http'=>array(
                    'method'=>"GET",
                    'header'=>"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"
                )
            );

            $context = stream_context_create($opts);

            $fileData = file_get_contents($dumpData, false, $context);
            echo $fileData;
                   }
      }
```

Code works sometimes and sometimes gives timeout error. Also my question is how to read this data from another machine through curl and save the data into file?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout :

```
$opts = [
    'http' => [
        // ...
        'timeout' => 100, // in seconds
    ],
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

Comment: the way i put the binary is ok?

Comment: how to create a curl function on the other machine to save the data into a a file?